# Is there any etymological connection between Aries and Ares?

Tags: etymology

I am wondering if there is any etymological connection between **Aries**, (the zodiac sign which is said to be ruled by the planet Mars, named for the Roman god of war) and **Ares** (the Greek god of war)?

Comment: No, they’re not related; see https://www.etymonline.com/word/Ares and https://www.etymonline.com/word/Aries for details. (Since the answer can be found by looking up the words in a general-reference source, I’ve voted to close the question as off-topic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any relation.

Aries comes from the [Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aries#Latin) of the same spelling, which is a cognate of the Ancient Greek [ἔριφος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%94%CF%81%CE%B9%CF%86%CE%BF%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) (young goat, kid) and suggested to be from the Proto-European [h₁er-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%81er-). Ares is from the Ancient Greek [Ἄρης](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%8C%CF%81%CE%B7%CF%82#Ancient_Greek), a proper noun